# JavaScript: What is exactly Declaring, Defining and initialising a variable or a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to understand what means exactly declaring, defining and initialising of a variable.

```
let a;      // If this is a declaration

let a = 22; // and this is initialising
```

how I define a variable?

can I initialise a function?

Comment: SOunds like you need some tutorials https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables

Answer (score 2):

> how I define a variable?

With a variable declaration. There is no distinction between defining a variable and declaring a variable. Well, okay, there's one case of defining but not declaring a variable: Assigning to an undeclared identifier in loose mode, which is what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because it creates a global variable without any declaration. Don't do that. :-)

> How I declare a function?

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/22173438#22173438) to another question lists the various ways you can create functions in JavaScript. One of those ways is a function declaration.

Some quick examples, but I doubt that question or that answer will get deleted:

Function Declaration:

```
function foo() {
}
```

Note we're not doing `x =` in front of it. Anything that would great that as an expression would make it not a declaration anymore.

"Anonymous" function Expression (which despite the term, sometimes create functions with names):

```
x = function() { };
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- this is the expression

doSomethingWith(function() { });
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- this is the expression
```

Named function Expression

```
x = function foo() { };
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- this is the expression

doSomethingWith(function foo() { });
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- this is the expression
```

Accessor Function Initializer (ES5+):

```
obj = {
    get foo() {         // << This is an accessor, specifically a getter
    },                  // <<
    set foo() {         // << This is an accessor, specifically a setter
    }                   // <<
}
```

Arrow Function Expression (ES2015+) (which, like anonymous function expressions, don't involve an explicit name, and yet can create functions with names); these can be *verbose* (with a `{ .. }` body) or *concise* (without `{}`):

```
x = () => { };
//  ^^^^^^^^^--- Verbose arrow function

doSomethingWith(() => { });
//              ^^^^^^^^^--- another verbose arrow function

y = () => expressionGoesHere;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- Concise arrow function

doSomethingWith(() => expressionGoesHere);
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- another concise arrow function
```

Method Declaration in Object Initializer (ES2015+)

```
obj = {
    foo() { // << This is the method declaration
    }       // <<
};
```

Constructor and Method Declarations in class (ES2015+)

```
class Example {
    foo() { // << This is the method declaration
    }       // <<
}
```

> can I initialise a function?

You can initialize a *variable* (or property) with a reference to a function:

```
let a = function() { };           // Variable
someObject.b = function() { };    // Object property
```

Comment: Many thanks. 
Does it mean that var a; is creating/defining/declaring a variable? and
var a = 5 is initialising a variable?
Do I understand you correctly that I cannot initialise a function?

Comment: @user1941537: Yes on the first thing. Re "initialize a function:" It doesn't really make sense to talk about "initializing" a function. You *create* functions.